# Regarding better way to Query MongoDB from Java

Tags: java, database, mongodb

Disclaimer: I am new to MongoDB. I just started to use it few days back. Sorry if my question doesn't make much sense.

Hello,

I am trying to make a Query to MongoDB from Java method, I want to create and make a query only if that parameter is not null. So let us say that my method is

```
public List<Object> getSomethingFromMongoDB(String searchParameter){
Query query = new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("something").is((searchParameter)));
}
```

Now I only want to search when SearchParameter only when it is notNull. Can I do this in a better way? I tried to check $ne but cannot understand how to apply it in my Java method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As much as I understood, you can just have `if (searchParameter == null || search Parameter.isEmpty())`

Comment: What if I have 10 parameters in my request?

Comment: You would be having them stored in a list or map just check the condition for all of them

Comment: I want to know if I can make the code cleaner by using some functionality of mongoDB.

Comment: *"  ...using some functionality of mongoDB"* - Then you are looking in the wrong place. Effectively MongoDB wants to see either "no conditions" `{}` or "a condition" `{ "something": "a" }`. Therefore if `searchParameter`is `null` then you simply don't `addCriteria` and just issue the `query` unaltered. So all you really need to do is break the logic up between `query = new Query()` and `query.addCriteria()` inside an `if`, just as it is logical to do.

Comment: You really don't want to make a round-trip to the server just because using MongoDB looks cleaner than an if-statement. Unless the MongoDB driver can do something smart (and I don't think it can) you should do the check on the client side before calling the server or you will take a totally unnecessary performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise the following:

```
public List<Document> getSomethingFromMongoDB(List<String> searchParameters){
        List<Document> results = new ArrayList<>();
        if (searchParameters == null) return results;
        Document criteria = new Document();
        searchParameters.forEach(parameter -> criteria.append("yourField",parameter));
        collection.find(criteria).iterator().forEachRemaining(results::add);
        return results;
}
```

If the parameters list is empty, you will just get all the documents.

If not, the corresponding criteria will be applied.

You could even get rid of the null-checking line, by making sure you pass a `new ArrayList()` for example, instead of null.